# How can i fix 2 warnings i'm getting in a script ? Warnings should be fixed?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have 2 warnings. It's not that i can't run the game but how can i fix the warnings ?

The first warning is:

Assets/My Scripts/Ai_Scripts/Editor/Editor.cs(56,26): warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.LookLikeControls()' is obsolete:`LookLikeControls and LookLikeInspector modes are deprecated. Use EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth and EditorGUIUtility.fieldWidth to control label and field widths.'

The line is:

```
EditorGUIUtility.LookLikeControls();
```

What should i change the line to ? What does it mean to use EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth and EditorGUIUtility.fieldWidth ? How do i use both ?

The second error is identical to the first just in another part in the script.

The warning in this method:

```
//called whenever the inspector gui gets rendered
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //this pulls the relative variables from unity runtime and stores them in the object
        //always call this first
        m_Object.Update();

        //show default iMove.cs public variables in inspector
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        //get Path Manager component by calling method GetWaypointArray()
        var path = GetPathTransform();

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        //make the default styles used by EditorGUI look like controls
        EditorGUIUtility.LookLikeControls();
        //display custom float input field to change value of variable "sizeToAdd"
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(m_Size);

        //draw bold delay settings label
        GUILayout.Label("Delay Settings:", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        //check whether a Path Manager component is set, if not display a label
        if (path == null)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("No path set.");

            //get StopAtPoint array count from serialized property and resize it to zero
            //(in case of previously defined delay settings, clear old data)
            m_Object.FindProperty(spArraySize).intValue = 0;
        }
        //path is set and boolean for displaying delay settings is true
        //(button below was clicked)
        else if (showDelaySetup)
        {
            //get StopAtPoint array reference by calling method GetStopPointArray()
            var stopPoints = GetStopPointArray();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            //begin a scrolling view inside GUI, pass in Vector2 scroll position 
            scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(105));

            //loop through waypoint array
            for (int i = 0; i < path.waypoints.Length; i++)
            {
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                //draw label with waypoint index,
                //increased by one (so it does not start at zero)
                GUILayout.Label((i + 1) + ".", GUILayout.Width(20));
                //create a float field for every waypoint delay slot
                var result = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(stopPoints[i], GUILayout.Width(50));

                //if the float field has changed, set waypoint delay to new input
                //(within serialized StopAtPoint array property)
                if (GUI.changed)
                    SetPointDelay(i, result);

                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
            //ends the scrollview defined above
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();

            //draw button for hiding of delay settings
            if (GUILayout.Button("Hide Delay Settings"))
            {
                showDelaySetup = false;
            }

            //draw button to set all delay value slots to the value specified in "delayAll"
            if (GUILayout.Button("Set All:"))
            {
                //loop through all delay slots, call SetPointDelay() and pass in "delayAll"
                for (int i = 0; i < stopPoints.Length; i++)
                    SetPointDelay(i, delayAll);
            }

            //create a float field for being able to change variable delayAll
            delayAll = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(delayAll, GUILayout.Width(50));

            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
        else
        {

            if (GUILayout.Button("Show Delay Settings"))
            {
                showDelaySetup = true;
            }
        }


        m_Object.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more context, show us the method the warning is happening in too.

Comment: Comment out the lines and see the difference in your custom Editor. If it looks okay to you, permanently remove the lines. If it doesn't, manually adjust `labelWidth` and `fieldWidth` to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the warning because `LookLikeControls()` is obsolete. Use `EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth` and `EditorGUIUtility.fieldWidth` to control label and field widths instead.